# ActionController::UnknownFormat on Bugsnag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

We got this error on our staging site yesterday and the error is `ActionController::UnknownFormat` and it happened at `users/sessions#new`. Here's the request that `Bugsnag` shows:

```
headers: {
           "Version": "HTTP/1.0",
           "Host": [Our site's IP],
           "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
           "X-Forwarded-For": "128.14.209.154",
           "Connection": "close",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36",
           "Accept": "../../../../../../../../../../etc/services{{",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
         }

httpMethod: GET

params: {
          "controller": "users/sessions",
          "action": "new"
        }

railsAction: users/sessions#new

referer: null

requestId: 6ecd71ba-31c8-4d55-9199-8e45e3d86246

url: [Our site's IP]

user_id: 128.14.209.154
```

No one really knows what is going on and as far as we were aware, no one was doing anything on that site at the moment.

A few things struck me as odd:

- This `Accept` in the headers: "Accept": `"../../../../../../../../../../etc/services{{"`
- The url/host: The url/host is our site's IP address instead of the site itself.
- The user_id: `user_id: 128.14.209.154`
- The `User-Agent`, specifically this: `(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)`. We all use Macbooks at our place, so no one should be attempting to access the site on a Windows computer.

Are we getting attacked by a malicious person? If so, what are they trying to do and what is our best course of action to handle this?

We are running on Rails 5.2.1 and nginx 1.10.3 (Ubuntu). Please let me know what other information I could provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> Are we getting attacked by a malicious person?

Someone's taking potshots. It's likely it's an automated attack.

Just make sure you're updated to the latest. This is probably related to [CVE-2019-5418](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-5418).

Comment: Ah I see, can you explain a little more on why you think someone is taking potshots? I'm not too familiar with these attacks, if possible can you give me some links to learn more about this? Thanks!

Comment: People scan the internet looking for things. You're just one of those things.